# quill.js: how to style a list

Tags: quill

I know that `UL` and `OL` (even v2.0.0 `TABLE`) has no existence in the `scroll` however I wondering if there is a way (or a trick) to style these elements (UL or OL, not the LI) through class or style attributor, eg.

```
<ul class="..."`
  <li ...
  <li ...
```

Comment: What's wrong with element-level CSS selectors like `ul { color: pink; }` ?

Comment: Nothing wrong, but I expect to style several lists with different styles.

Comment: I suspect your best bet is to extend the `List` blot and roll your own

Comment: I agree, unfortunately I think there is no other way